# Sonar doesn't report code coverage for AspectJ

Tags: aspectj, sonarqube

Our Sonar installation 3.7.4 is not reporting on AspectJ classes. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: This is not a particularly smart way to ask a question. Please be more specific. Which coverage tool do you use? Sonar is a tool for static code analysis. What do you mean by "AspectJ classes"? Aspects or classes affected by aspects? What kind of coverage do you want? Or do you really rather want to get a report about which advice are woven into which methods (cross-reference in the style of [ajdoc](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ajdoc-ref.html))? Which error messages or other problem symptoms do you see? Can you provide config snippets or code to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

AspectJ files are not indexed in SonarQube because there's currently no plugin for this technology. So in any case, you won't be able to see them in SonarQube, may it be to know the lines of code of the code coverage.